# coldfusion generate rewritemap for web.config

Tags: coldfusion, web-config, coldfusion-10

I have a rewritemap in my web.config that rewrites urls.

```
<rewriteMap name="Products"> 
<add key="Ipad_3" value="4399" />
<add key="Ipad_Mini" value="4399" />
</rewriteMap>
```

Instead of manually inserting new `<add>` tags, I would like coldfusion script to generate `<add>` tags with data taken from database and insert it into web.config. Please advice

Comment: Which bit are you stuck with?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't going to work the way that you probably want it to.

Changes to web.config aren't recognized until your IIS application pool is recycled. Recycling your application pool every time you add or delete a product seems like a bad idea. Not to mention the fact that if anything goes wrong, your entire website will go down because of a bad web.config file.

You should look into using a dynamic rewrite tool like [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) instead.

Comment: Isapi Rewrite supports map files which can provide this exact behavior as well. Changes to the map file are picked up immediately.